# mysql: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: mysql, passwords, ubuntu-16.04

I've done a search on this, and though there are many results, all of the proposed solutions seem to fail for one reason or another.

One thing to note is that many of the solutions require entering mysql and then making some configuration changes to alter the user account. For the record, even so much as entering 'mysql' or 'mysql -u root' (and so on) at the command prompt will bring up the error.

I'm just using mysql for some big data classes, so I don't need a server and I don't need to connect any apps or anything like that (although I will be running HBase).

When I did the initial install:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

I was never prompted for a password at any point. Likewise, if I run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.7
```

I get the message:

```
Checking if update is needed.
This installation of MySQL is already upgraded to 5.7.19, use --force if you still need to run mysql_upgrade
```

Running it with '--force' just brings about the same error.

I've tried running:

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

But I only get returned to the command prompt with "[1] 16654"

Just in case, I set chmod 777 on '/var/lib/mysql*' as well as '/var/run/mysqld'

I have also tried the unix instructions posted below, to no avail:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

The error log from /var/log/mysql was a bit unwieldy, so I have uploaded it here:

https://pastebin.com/exDeKHeA

Thanks in advance for any responses. If any other files or info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: It appears the the server never finishes startup to create a socket to be running: `[ERROR] Could not create unix socket lock file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.lock.` which is then followed by: `[ERROR] Unable to setup unix socket lock file.` and then: `[ERROR] Aborting` ... what are the permissions to `/var/run/mysqld`?  Also, have a look [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04) as there appears to be more steps to install.

Comment: Thank you Paul. I set the permissions on /var/run/mysqld to 777

vaughn@vaughn-notebook:~$ ls -l /var/run/

drwxr-xr-x  2 mysql mysql  100 Jul 24 12:30 mysqld

Comment: So does that mean that it's running now, or not? The permission to `/var/run/mysqld` should not need 777, as 755 should be enough.

Comment: It is still not running. I tried a reinstall of mysql since changing the permissions and still get 'access denied.' New log is at:

https://pastebin.com/CTWXj15n

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you check the link mentioned earlier. It seems that there are other steps to the mysql install to be done? Meanwhile, I'll look at that log in a moment.

Comment: Farther down in the first log, the server did start and was running (likely after applying your previous permission changes): `[Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306`, followed by: `[Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.` and `socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  (Ubuntu)`. Same in the 2nd log, so I did "jump to conclusion" on the error, but I do see the failed login attempts in both files.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the link initially. However, I only get as far as step 3: "sudo mysql_secure_installation" and then I get prompted for a root password, which fails regardless of what I type in.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are MANY reasons that could cause the trouble that you see. Note the 'Related' links to the right, there are at least 5 with your same error.  Not sure if this might work, but in the mysql config, change the the bind address from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0.  Then save and restart the mysql server and try again?

Comment: I faced the same problem with latest MariaDB, the problem was that it doesn't allow root logins without sudo. So, `sudo mysql -u root` did it for me.